# Fix glyphicon aspect when datepicker is a required field

Tags: jquery, parsley.js, bootstrap-datepicker

I have a form with a datepicker that's being validated using ParsleyJS. The datepicker has a glyphicon next to the input and the input is required.

When the user didn't enter any date, Parsley displays an error. However, when this occurs, the glyphicon span gets a strange behaviour and doesn't match the height of the input.

Below is the code I'm using and a demo of what's happening (check the date input).

What can I do to solve this?

```
<form>
    <div class="row">
        <div class='col-sm-6'>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker2'>
                    <input type='text' class="form-control" data-parsley-required="true" />
                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            <input type="submit" />
        </div>
    </div>
</form>

<script>
    $(function() {
        $('#datetimepicker2').datetimepicker();
        $('form').parsley();
    });

</script>
```

[image]

Comment: Nice question, but very poorly written. Some guidelines for you to write a better question and have a better feedback are: write the code on the question. The image is not sufficient. Also, fiddles are always welcome. Also, be sure to point which plugins you're using, in this case what's the datepicker plugin..

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that Parsley always positions the `<ul>` with the errors right next to the elements with errors, but in some particular cases, such as yours, you want as a child of another element (in your case you want it to be at the same level as `<div class="input-group date">`.

So you can use the `parsley:field:error` event to accomplish that. Try the following code, and be sure to update `div.date` according to your HTML.

```
$.listen('parsley:field:error', function(parsleyField) {
    var elem = parsleyField.$element;

    // Whenever we're dealing with datepickers
    if (elem.parent('div.date').length > 0) {
        // Get the parent element of the input
        var topParent = elem.parent('div.date').parent('div');

        // Find the error list and append it to the parent instead of the input
        topParent.find('ul.parsley-errors-list').each(function() {
            // move $(this) to the bottom of top parent
            topParent.append($(this));
        });
    }
});
```

Check [this jsfiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/milz/vyo257rp/1/).